# PySpark quickly starting problem on windows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I just write the code like official documentation:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from datetime import datetime, date

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    (1, 2., 'string1', date(2000, 1, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0)),
    (2, 3., 'string2', date(2000, 2, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 2, 12, 0)),
    (3, 4., 'string3', date(2000, 3, 1), datetime(2000, 1, 3, 12, 0))
])
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
df.printSchema()
```

But I get the exception like:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (QRN-NOTEBOOK executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:131)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:535)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:189)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:176)
        ... 14 more
```

How can I solve it?

I have tried to downgrade the java version from 11 to 8, and use `conda install` instead of `pip install`.

Comment: Do you run the code from an IDE, or do you run by using spark-submit?

Comment: I run the code from vscode. What is spark-submit?

Comment: You can try adding the PYSPARK_PYTHON=python env variable, it might helps. Important to add it to the cell where you start the spark session, in case of using a notebook.

Comment: Thank you. But I solve my problem by using the WSL environment, hhh. I suspect that it's just the bug of windows11!